# add a new component to java maven project

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-3, pom.xml

I have a maven project that contains many components. I need to add a new one called "Component" witch has one module like described in the list below:

- Component

  - com.module

    - src

      - main

        - java
        - resources

          - META-INF

            - module
      - test

        - java

Thanks

Comment: What is your actual question? "Component" could be an additional module in a multi-module maven project. Is this your intention? If it is, then the structure doesn't fit very well as there is an intermediate level "com.module" that looks like a package.

Comment: I need to add a new module with many packages but in for now I need to create one package like descried in the list

Comment: Packages are placed either in the src/main/java or the src/test/java directories (you can do the same with the resource directories as they are merged with the source/target packages at runtime). Based on the assumption that "Component" is a maven module, it seems to me as the structure you ask for is not valid.

Comment: Are you inf act talking about [multi-module maven project](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

When you need to add a new component as a maven module with many packages, maybe this would be a suitable approach. The module itself is then part of a multi module project (see [Maven by Example](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html)):

- Component [Name of the maven module]

  - src

    - main

      - java

        - com.module.a
        - com.module.b
        - ...
      - resources

        - META-INF

          - module
    - test

      - java
      - resources